# How to create a query for a known value on a known field, with a known date between 2 unknown dates)

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The task is to find a known value in the specified field. Condition: There is a system date or a date that I want to use. This date must be between 2 dates ( the fields where the dates are known), that is, you need to check all the dates in the database, + additional condition:

it is necessary that the found string had in itself a previously known field marked IS NULL

The code written in Sql, below working.

```
select b.* from nc_proc b where b.code_proc = 'S.2.2' and b.date_on >= '12-AUG-19' and  b.d_off  IS NULL  and b.date_off > '12-AUG-19';
```

'12-AUG-19' is a variable that is sent to me(more precisely, I form it from the system time)

'S. 2. 2' is a variable that I get and which is the main search.

How to make a request ?

here is an example that tried to make

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.* FROM nc_proc b WHERE b.code_proc = ?1 and b.date_on  > ?2 and  b.d_off  IS NULL  and b.date_off > ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
List <NcProc> findByCodeProcList2 (String value, String systemDate);
```

This don't work.

Please tell me how to fix.  And is it possible not to use the query manually, but to do with the built-in keywords spring data ? Then this option would be better.

**Update**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.* FROM nc_proc b WHERE b.code_proc = ?1 and ?2 b.date_on BETWEEN b.date_off and  b.d_off  IS NULL", nativeQuery = true)
    List <NcProc> findByCodeProcList2 (String value, String systemDate);
```

> Hibernate: SELECT b.* FROM nc_proc b WHERE b.code_proc = ? and ?
>   b.date_on BETWEEN b.date_off and  b.d_off  IS NULL 
>   11:02:58:871  WARN http-nio-8080-exec-1
>   o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 920, SQLState: 42000
>   19-сентября-20 11:02:58:871 ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-1
>   o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:142 - ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

In addition, I was told that **BETWEEN** includes the left and right restriction, and it is necessary that the desired date was in the specified interval and is not equal to the left and right restriction.

**Update**

it's work

```
 @Query(value = "select * from nc_proc where code_proc = ?1 " +
        "and date_on <= TO_DATE(?2, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') " +
        "and TO_DATE(?2, 'yyyy-mm-dd  HH24:MI:SS ') < date_off " +
        "and d_off IS NULL",
        nativeQuery = true)
  NcProc findByCodeProc(String codeProc, String systemDate);
```

I wanted not to use the native record in the future.

Who knows how to make an expression from the keywords spring-data ?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `NcProc` entity? When writing JPQL, you have to follow the structure of your entity, so without knowing what your entity looks like, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Please be sure to post your question in English, e.g. there's the word Обновление in your question. Most users, including me, will have a hard time deciphering it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help on the Spring side, but for your queries I think you want something like:

```
SELECT b.* FROM nc_proc b WHERE b.code_proc = ?1 AND b.date_on > ?2 AND b.date_off < ?2 AND b.d_off IS NULL
```

It's unclear from your question whether the dates go `b.date_on > '12-AUG-19' > b.date_off` or the other way around, `b.date_on < '12-AUG-19' < b.date_off`. So you might have to switch the > < operators.